# Change color of Ubuntu MATE 15.10

Tags: appearance, ubuntu-mate

As it seems the color green is default color of Ubuntu MATE. Highlighted text is in green, bars are in green, etc... How do I change it to something other?

Answer (score 3):

As Muzaffar suggests, you can change the 'Selected items' background color when customizing theme.

However some greens won't disappear only just because of this setting, some GTK+3 objects remain green.

I followed [this](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/can-you-tell-the-difference-ubuntu-mate-vs-ubuntu-11-04/2119/8) post.

What you have to do is to copy `/usr/share/themes/Ambiant-MATE` to: `~/.themes/Ambiant-MATE` (or an other theme, if you want, ex.: Radiant-MATE)

> Then inside these files:
>
> - gtk-3.0/gtk-main.css
> - gtk-3.0/settings.ini
> - gtk-2.0/gtkrc
>
> Replace `#87A752` (Ubuntu MATE's green) with `#F17949` (Ubuntu's
>   Orange), and re-log in for changes to take effect.

But it still wasn't enough for me, because progressbars and checkboxes remained green. Then I found the `gtk-3.0/assets` folder. There, I had to manually change the color of every single greenish asset with Gimp. I used the Hue-Saturation tool with the following parameters:

```
Hue: -50
Lightness: 6
Saturation: 68
```

This gave me brownish-orangish items, not quite like the modern default ubuntu orange, but much better than the mate-green. I think it's similar to the old color scheme from the ubuntu 8-era. If you play a bit with that numbers, you might get a better result.

*Note: I'm using Ubuntu Mate 16.04 however it's very likely that it works for 15.10 as well*

[image]

### Update

I simply copied the assets from a *normal* Ubuntu 16.04 installation. Now, every single control looks the same as in Unity.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8EY0Cnt1-s0TjVUdEhySHJQcTA/view?pref=2&pli=1) you can download both Ambiance and Radiance themes. You have to copy the `gtk-3.0/assets` folder.

Comment: The linked file in Google Drive has been configured to not allow downloading for viewers. Is that on purpose? Google Drive `Details` view for the linked file says `Download Permission` `Viewers cannot download`.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen That's definitely not on purpose. Have you tried to download it while signed in with a gmail account?

Comment: Yeah, I even added it to my Google Drive but I still cannot get it to work. It's kind of weird that I can add that `.tar.gz` to my drive but I still cannot get any file out from the package. All I can do is see list of files inside the package.

Comment: According to Google Drive UI it has been shared as "Anyone: can view" and "Download Permission: Viewers cannot download".

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen Should be downloadable now. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

From top left corner go to **System** - **Preferences** - **Appearance**. (You can go through **Control Center**, as well  )

From there go to **Themes** menu and click on the "**Customize**" button on the lower right corner of the window.

Go to **Colours** tab and have fun:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it doesnt change all the colours. Let's say highlighted songs in Rythmbox are still in green. How do I change this?

Comment: You will have to change the whole theme. Just try choosing another theme.

Comment: But I like this one, only the green color I dislike. So no other options?

Comment: I have no **Colors** tab at Ubuntu mate 18.04, Where did it go to ?